# javascript for loop adding to [i]

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a GAS script working, however it is populating the entire column with the var domainCell when their are only entries in 6 rows. So I am not sure do I need to create a if statement asking if a column is blank?

```
// Sets users names
 for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
fullNames.push([names[i][0].substr(0,5) + '_' + names[i][1].substr(0,5) + names[i][2].slice( -3 ) + domainCell]); // The domain Cell is populating down the page 
}
```

tried this

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

if (names[i][0] !== ss.isBlank && names[i][1] !== ss.isBlank && names[i][2] !== ss.isBlank) {
    fullNames.push([names[i][0].substr(0,5) + '-----------' + names[i][1].substr(0,5) + names[i][2].slice( -3 ) + domainCell]);
}
else {
   fullNames.push([names[i][0].substr(0,5) + '_' + names[i][1].substr(0,5) + names[i][2].slice( -3 ) + domainCell]);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please cut short your code and show only the part of the code which corresponds to the problem?

Comment: ok there  i cut it down to the are I believe is the problem- domainCell is populating down the entire range & I want it only to populate when their is data within [names[i][0].substr(0,5) + '_' + names[i][1].substr(0,5) + names[i][2].slice( -3 )]

Comment: When will there not be data?

Comment: It's really hard to answer this without knowing what `names` is going to be (possibly you don't even know though), but yes the best thing to do is have a check for the presence/structure of `names[i]`.

Comment: This is in a spreadsheet so it is checking a range and for each row it  concatenates the columns within the row. So i have data entered in say 10 rows, but the last field the domainCell continues to populate down the page

Comment: yes @mralexlau your right, I dont know what data will be entered into these fields. But it seems you should be able to ask "is their data" or "no data"

Answer (score 0):

If you're only goal is to make sure data exists, consider this example:

```
names = [['Bob', 'Cindy', 'Tom'], ['Joe', 'Jane']]
```

Where the first subarray has 3 elements (like you're hoping for) but the second only has 2.

You can use the check `if (names[i][0] !== undefined && names[i][1] !== undefined && names[i][2] !== undefined)` to check to make sure all 3 entries exist for a given row. In this example the first entry would be pushed onto fullNames, but the second would be skipped since `names[1][2]` is undefined.

Comment: Still cant wrap my head around what is going on here- Sorry I am new to Js & GAS
    'for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {'
    
    if (names[i][0] !== ss.isBlank && names[i][1] !== ss.isBlank && names[i][2] !== ss.isBlank) {
    fullNames.push([names[i][0].substr(0,5) + '-----------' + names[i][1].substr(0,5) + names[i][2].slice( -3 ) + domainCell]);
    }
    else {
       fullNames.push([names[i][0].substr(0,5) + '_' + names[i][1].substr(0,5) + names[i][2].slice( -3 ) + domainCell]);
    }
    
  } `

Comment: Still cant wrap my head around what is going on here- Sorry I am new to Js & GAS - I will add the code I am trying, to my post above since I cant get it to show proper within comments. I tried using your undefined and then seen GAS has command isBlank- both with no luck- I must be doing something wrong